# Central alignment of equation with numcases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment, cases

I have the latex code for an equation with numcases

```
\begin{numcases}
{a =}
bbbbbbbbbbb, \\
ccccccccccc, 
\end{numcases}
```

which gives the result

[image]

how to get the whole equation aligned centrally, instead of aligned so that "a" is in the center of the column??

Comment: Please don't show only a code snippet, because it does not really show, why your equation is not centered or which packages you are using to define `numcases`. Showing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) would help us to reproduce your problem immediately and also to test our ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `empheq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={a=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
   & bbbbbbbbbbb, \\
   & ccccccccccc,
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you really need to number the rows, I suggest to add `subequations`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left={a=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
   & bbbbbbbbbbb, \\
   & ccccccccccc, 
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cases` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{a=}
   bbbbbbbbbbb, \\
   ccccccccccc, 
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I checked and I am using \usepackage{amsmath,cases} - do you know what could be causing the alignment problem? Could something else be interfering with it? Thank you

Comment: @Nigel1 What kind of alignment is it? Alignment of my code is centered.